# How to catch ray which is going from camera to my ground?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I shoot a ray from the camera to the intersection with the position of the mouse click and my ground, but the result - `NullReferenceException`. Here is the code:

```
public class StopperByClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Ray ray;
    public RaycastHit hit;
    public GameObject cube;
    public GameObject plane;


    void Update()
    {
        ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector3 dir = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward * 100);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, dir, Color.green);
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 10) && hit.collider.gameObject == plane)
            {
                float x = (hit.point.x > 67232f) ? hit.point.x : 67232f;
                float y = (hit.point.y > 22544f) ? hit.point.y : 22544.5f;
                float z = (hit.point.z > 46474f) ? hit.point.z : 46474f;
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
                cube.transform.position = pos;
                Instantiate(cube);

                //Debug.Log(hit.transform.position.x + " " + hit.transform.position.y + " " + hit.transform.position.z);                
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Help me please, what is wrong?

Comment: I can see you provided sample code. `NullReferenceException` usually occurs in unity when there is unassigned reference variable. So please provide actual/complete code. And also mention, on which line the code is throwing exception.

Comment: See this : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/437481/screenpointtorayinputmouseposition-throws-nullrefe.html

Comment: ray object is null!

Comment: I edited code. tell me please whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You might not have a main camera, make sure your main camera has the "MainCamera" tag since `Camera.main` has the following documentation:

> The first enabled camera tagged "MainCamera" (Read Only).
>
> Returns null if there is no such camera in the scene.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html

<s>Another possibility is that you have not assigned anything to your `plane` variable which I expect is a public property which you should assign via the inspector.</s>(Asker has ruled out this possibility)

---

If you want to acquire your camera differently (if your script is attached to it) you can do this:

```
private Camera _cameraComponent;

void Initialize() {
    _cameraComponent = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void Update() {
    ray = _cameraComponent.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    ...
}
```

---

Answer to edited question:

You're not drawing a representative debug ray for your raycast. Your ray does to a `distance` of `10` whereas your debug ray goes to a `distance` of `100`

I suspect your plane is farther than `10` units away (confirmed by asker in comments)

---

Answer to wrong position comment:

```
float x = (hit.point.x > 67232f) ? hit.point.x : 67232f;
float y = (hit.point.y > 22544f) ? hit.point.y : 22544.5f;
float z = (hit.point.z > 46474f) ? hit.point.z : 46474f;
```

These are the lines causing the behaviour. All cubes you create are from clicks below the minimums you've set so they are being spawned at those minimums instead.

In case you are confused, `x = (x > n) ? x : n;` means if `x` is lower than `n`, make `x = n`. Which could be expressed `float x = Mathf.min(hit.point.x, 67343f)`

I'm curious about your reasons to do this. Are you ensuring that the cube can't spawn off of the plane? If so, this is unnecessary because your raycast can only give you points on the plane. In which case you should simply remove those 3 lines and make `cub.transform.position = hit.point`

Comment: but I cling to this script on camera. No, i assigned plane object!

Comment: That doesn't matter. If you're calling `Camera.main` it doesn't care where you're calling it from, it will always return the first enabled camera tagged "MainCamera"

Comment: ok, i changed tag in camera to maincamera and there is not nullexception. But i cant catch the position of my mouse when i click on my ground

Comment: Can you specify the position of your camera and the position of your floor please (it might be too far away)? Can you make sure your `plane` variable is correctly set (it might be comparing to null)?

Comment: i have drawn ray just to see whats happening and it does not touch to my problem. I want on my mouseclick i would have created cubes on position where i would click on

Comment: You're still not answering my main theory here. What is the distance between your `MainCamera` and the `plane`?

Comment: Plane (67228.55,22543.96,46464.23)  and camera (67213.1,22547.37,46463.93). As i understand it is 16. But it is the distance between center of my plane and camera.

Comment: @AndrewLawmaking Increase the length of your ray. Just for testing if it works in general you can set it from 10 to some large number, like 10000 or so.

Comment: @Gunnar B. Ok! the cubes are created by my mouse click, but the position of any cube is not differ from the position of another cube, even i click on any part of my ground.

Comment: That's probably because of the limits you're applying on all of them, depending on how big your plane is, `float x = (hit.point.x > 67232f) ? hit.point.x : 67232f;` will put all your cubes at `x = 67232f`. May I ask why your objects are placed so far from 0?

Comment: They are all at `67232, 22544.5, 46474`? What is the reason for doing that check? If the ray collides with the plane the cubes should always be at the respective point on the plane.

Comment: Confirms my suspicions, none of the points you are clicking are above the limits you've placed on x, y, and z so they are being clamped to those limits.

Comment: @sokkyoku There is no real reason, i am a beginner in unity so somehow i did such so.

Comment: In that case I advise you to move everything as close to (0, 0, 0) as you can, it makes the numbers easier to work with :)